# How to release memory in graphic cards?

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-quadro

I am using NVIDIA Quadro P620.

I have used ffmpeg to transcode with my GPU several times using the command

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.avi -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

Then ffmpeg stops transcoding and telling me off:

```
No decoder surfaces left
```

It seems the GPU memory got filled up and not released. If I remove *-hwaccel_output_format cuda* option, transcoding works again.

How do I flush GPU memory? How do I manage GPU memory in windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a known bug:
 [#7562 open defect
using -hwaccel nvdec produces 'No decoder surfaces left' with interlaced input and 3 or more b-frames](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7562).

The proposed workarounds in this post were:

- Add the parameter `-extra_hw_frames 3`
- Use the filter `scale_cuda` or `yadif_cuda`.

Comment: Can you tell me the usage? when i put extra_hw_frames, it will say "Codec AVOption extra_hw_frames (Number of extra hardware frames to allocate for the user) specified for output file #0 (gpu3.mp4) is not an encoding option." And when I put filter=scale_cuda, it doesn't recognize. 
BTW, what's the mechanism to fix the problem by adding these flags? The page you provided, i also spotted, way too technical for me. I don't know what they are on about.

Comment: Are you using the latest ffmpeg? On which operating system?

Comment: Yes, version 4.4-full_build

Answer (score 0):

Trying to enhance the above solution.

```
  ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 5 -i input.mp4  -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4
```

We need to add the extra threads that are needed after the hwaccel output format.
If you paste it after input you might get `Codec AVOption extra_hw_frames (Number of extra hardware frames to allocate for the user)`

You can play with extra_hw_frames based on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the change in the default amount of b frames from 0 to auto (that is -1). Happened here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/a0949d0bcb0eee2f3fffcf9a4810c0295d14c0dc

Workaround is to use -bf 0 after -c:v h264_nvenc or add -extra_hw_frames 5 or more before input or remove some threads from -hwaccel cuda (threads is another bug here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8948#comment:4).

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7562 is specifically about deinterlacing content, it appears to be fixed.